# What is volumelcon.icns

Tags: macos, icon

Can someone tell me what `volumelcon.icns` is?  I'm attempting to remove unnecessary items from File Explorer and don't want to remove something that is required.

Answer (score 1):

.VolumeIcon.icns is an invisible file which holds the display icon for each attached disk.

If you delete it - not worth it as it's only about 1MB anyway - it will simply be re-created.

[image]

As a general rule - if it's invisible… leave it alone.

BTW, Mac doesn't have a 'file explorer' it has Finder.